# nonnegative Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-transform, fourier-analysis

Let $\widehat{f}(\xi)$ be Fourier transform of $f$ given by 
\begin{align}
\widehat{f}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-ix\cdot\xi}f(x)dx.
\end{align}
 Suppose that $\widehat{f}(\xi)$ is nonnegative and locally integrable function, easily seems (by inverse Fourier transform) that 
\begin{align}
\Vert f\Vert_{L^{\infty}} \leq \Vert \widehat{f}\Vert_{L^1}.
\end{align} 
How to show that there is a positive constant $c>0$ such that 
\begin{align}
\Vert \widehat{f}\Vert_{L^1}\leq c \Vert f\Vert_{L^{\infty}}.
\end{align}

Comment: What do you call "the other inequality" and where your question originates from?

Comment: How to show that there is a positive constant $c>0$ such that 
\begin{align}
\Vert \widehat{f}\Vert_{L^1}\leq c \Vert f\Vert_{L^{\infty}}
\end{align}

Comment: My question originate from Lemarie's book: "recents developments in the Navier-Stokes problem" p168.

Comment: I meant $f(t)$ of course...

Comment: Yemon Choi, in Lemarie's book he say that 
\begin{align}
\Vert f\Vert_{L^{\infty}}=\Vert \widehat{f}\Vert_{L^1}
\end{align}

Comment: [deleted earlier, erroneous comments]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $\hat f$ is nonnegative, then (up to a factor), 
$$f(0)=\int \hat f=\Vert \hat f \Vert_1 = \Vert f \Vert_\infty.$$

Comment: tanks so much Michael Renardy